# Regex to remove all attributes from nested html tags - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, regex

I want to remove html tag's attributes using regex. It could be any html element and allow nested elements like:

```
<div fadeout"="" style="margin:0px;" class="xyz">
    <img src="abc.jpg" alt="" />
    <p style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    The event is celebrating its 50th anniversary K&ouml;&nbsp;
    <a style="margin:0px;" href="http://www.germany.travel/">exhibition grounds in Cologne</a>.
    </p>
    <p style="padding:0px;"></p>
    <p style="color:black;">
       <strong>A festival for art lovers</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

or it could be like

`<span style="margin: 0;"><p class="abc"> Test text</p></span>`

because of security reason, need to remove attributes

What I have tried to remove

```
s/(<\w+)\s+[^>]*/$1/

<*\b[^<]*>(?:[^<]+(?:<(?!\/?div\b)[^<]*)*|(?R))*<\/*>\s*
<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>
```

but not working

Comment: Why would you try to use regex for this? Attributes may not be quoted, they may be quoted with single quotes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69902509/227299 Anyone trying to deal with this regex in the future is going to HATE you! 

Comment: There is no security requirement that forces you to remove all attributes, you're doing the wrong thing. It's very likely that you'll either break intended functionality or that you'll still have an XSS hole. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html which can guide you.

Answer (score 2):

[Regex should not be used to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Instead, you should use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the string, loop through each element's attributes and use [`Element.removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute):

```js
const str = `<div fadeout"="" style="margin:0px;" class="xyz">
    <img src="abc.jpg" alt="" />
    <p style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    The event is celebrating its 50th anniversary K&ouml;&nbsp;
    <a style="margin:0px;" href="http://www.germany.travel/">exhibition grounds in Cologne</a>.
    </p>
    <p style="padding:0px;"></p>
    <p style="color:black;">
       <strong>A festival for art lovers</strong>
    </p>
</div>`

function stripAttributes(html){
  const parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html')
  parsed.body.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(elem => [...elem.attributes].forEach(attr => elem.removeAttribute(attr.name)))
  return parsed.body.innerHTML;
}

console.log(stripAttributes(str))
```

Comment: To the OP: Be careful because removing all attributes is very likely problematic. Why would you have an `<img>` without an `src`. Why would you have an `<a>` without an `href` or at least a name? I would stay away from trying to sanitize HTML on your own. Use a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you not to use regexes in this situation, but if you dont have a choice maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
/<\s*([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\s.*?>/gi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about working with the DOM is that you have a whole set of tools available to you that were designed specifically for manipulating a DOM! And yet people insist on treating this complex structured data format as though it's just a dumb string and start hacking away at it with regex.

Use the right tool for the job.

```js
function removeAttributesRecursively(el) {
  Array.from(el.attributes).forEach(function(attr) {
    // you'll probably want to include extra logic here to
    // preserve some attributes (a href, img src, etc)
    // instead of blindly removing all of them
    el.removeAttribute(attr.name);
  });
  // recurse:
  Array.from(el.children).forEach(function(child) {
    removeAttributesRecursively(child)
  })
}

const root = document.getElementById('input');

removeAttributesRecursively(root)

console.log(root.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <div fadeout="" style="margin:0px;" class="xyz">
    <img src="abc.jpg" alt="" />
    <p style="margin-bottom:10px;">
      The event is celebrating its 50th anniversary K&ouml;&nbsp;
      <a style="margin:0px;" href="http://www.germany.travel/">exhibition grounds in Cologne</a>.
    </p>
    <p style="padding:0px;"></p>
    <p style="color:black;">
      <strong>A festival for art lovers</strong>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was about to add a comment asking you to remove the extremely hard to read `Array.prototype.slice.apply` calls :D

Comment: Oldschool, sorry.  Updated to use ES6 methods :)

Comment: @Spectric's method is better anyway; I should've thought to just select every element in the first place instead of recursing